# Mechanize Unsupported Scheme after form submit

Tags: ruby, forms, web-crawler, mechanize

I follow the [Mechanize guide](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_rdoc.html), but can't submit form.
My idea is to get invoice by a query through Telegram bot. Since there is a captcha I thought that I could read captcha image src with Mechanize to send that image through Telegram. Than, I would input digits that I can see on image and send in back to Mechanize to fill second input field. 
Code:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Chrome'

page = agent.get('https://ercdmd.ru/?gpay')

form = page.forms.first

form.gpay_abon = '04-0000000000'

captcha_url = "https://ercdmd.ru/captcha.php?time=#{Time.now.to_i}000"

p captcha_url

captcha = gets.chomp

form.captcha = captcha

page = agent.submit(form, form.buttons.first)
```

Output:

```
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:177:in `block (2 levels) in initialize': Mechanize::UnsupportedSchemeError (Mechanize::UnsupportedSchemeError) from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:645:in `call' from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:645:in `resolve' from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:234:in `fetch' from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize.rb:1323:in `post_form' from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize.rb:584:in `submit' from parser.rb:26:in `<main>'
```

Comment: If you look at the action of that form it's a javascript function (which isn't really valid).

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there anything I could do with it or it's something like defence from web crawlers?

Comment: No, it's an inexperienced web developer trying to do something tricky.